# Edit mode circle selected P does not show any options for separation

Tags: mesh

I am new to blender and trying to use edit mode and circle selection in order to separate parts of a mesh so the separate parts are small for import into Roblox.
I have my mesh cantered and edit mode activated and pressed C and selected a section from the centre of the mesh which showed up as selected but when I then press P for separation nothing shows.
I took a screenshot.
[image: Circle Selected No P]

Comment: Did you press enter/escape after using the Circle tool? If the Circle tool is still 'active' you can't use another tool like separate.

Answer (score 1):

Until a tool has 'finished', you can't start a new one. In the case of the *Circle Select* tool this means either pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to 'Confirm' the tool, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> to 'Cancel' the tool (though in this case cancelling doesn't actually 'undo' the selection you made, it just ends it).